# Magento configurable product dependent attribute

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, configurable-product, dependency, associate-products

Currently I am working on a  project where there is requirement of the associate product dependency.
E.g : If have an computer and have associated product  brand X,Y,Z and and RAM of brand X,Y,Z
If I select brand X than the RAM should only show from BRAND X. I am not looking for an exact code for
it, just an approach how can it be achieved,if it is. Thank you for the help in advance.